# Is it also not good for seo to start and end with same word in all pages

Tags: seo, spam

I searched but did not find any good exact information so I am questioning here to get information from experienced persons.

1. Is it normal for search engines that every page-title of website pages start and end with same word with only un-matching middle word?
2. Also all website pages URLs can start with the same word?
3. Also all `<h1>` tags in website pages can end with the same word?

This is easy to set same words for each page, but which way is best for seo for all pages?

Comment: As for SEO, you really should visit better websites. Search performance is not about keywords. What you are suggesting will yield you poor performance and possibly get you penalized as a spammer. Seriously. Just create good content and do not put the cart before the horse.

Comment: @closetnoc ok, thanks for comment, but what when use same word at only end in all pages like many websites do with titles with company name at end.

Comment: That is branding and is one of many signals that the site is sending to the search engines.

Comment: @closetnoc thanks for info, but can't we use other keyword to rank better in all titles end and can't also use branding/keyword in h1?

Comment: please see what this site is doing to titles: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/&ei=0z8rV9rRJougugT0hpqoCQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=667

Comment: I have 46 branding signals. H1 will not help with branding. This answer can help - follow the links: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87089/branding-in-terms-of-seo/87092#87092 see also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88621/does-using-h4-and-h5-tags-in-a-list-of-products-improve-seo/88628#88628 http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86695/do-you-get-penalised-for-duplicate-keyword-anchor-text-within-your-own-website/86699#86699 and this favorite http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: Yes. That is branding. That is the company name.

Comment: @closetnoc thanks for links, i am reading the answers. but did you see that website titles starts with same word "best"

Comment: That is poor SEO practice. Who searches for best *anything*? It is a waste of space and effort. ;-) The general rule is to be natural and not chase keywords especially terms that people really do not search for like *best*. The key is to create your content adequately with topics in mind and use appropriate language. The better you can cover a topic semantically, the better. It is not about keywords and keyword matches. It is about search intent and semantics. Chasing keywords too much only narrows your search potential.

Comment: @closetnoc i understand its not natural, but people do search for "best smartwatch" 49,500 per month according to google keyword tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it normal for search engines that every page-title of website pages
>   start and end with same word with only un-matching middle word?

Normal? No. Somewhat common, yes...for sites that are attempting to game the search engines.  This is not a recommended action for most sites.

> Also all website pages URLs can start with the same word?

I wouldn't do this.  Makes your site look spammy.

> Also all  tags in website pages can end with the same word?

You can but I still wouldn't do this because, again, spammy behavior.

A lot of information and sites on SEO are way out of date or was never good advice to begin with. The way to good rankings in the search engines now is a combination of on-page and off-page elements of which the exact keywords on the site plays only a small factor. In fact, it is easier to hurt your SEO by gaming the keywords than it is to help yourself.

Create sites than are mobile-responsive, fast to load, and provide clear navigation combined with a good user experience. Create content that delivers your message in a clear and easy-to-consume manner, using language that is appropriate to the audience. If you do that, your issues with SEO and keywords will resolve themselves. Gaming the system will only net you a short-term benefit at best and, at worst, sets you up for severe long-term penalties.

---

To use your "Best Smartwatch" example in the comments above, it is perfectly natural to have a page on your site titled:

> "Which is the best smartwatch on the market today?"

and to also have an opening sentence like:

> "There has been an explosion of smartwatches in the last year with
>   devices running Android, iOS and other operating systems. But which is
>   the best smartwatch today?"

and then go from there.  Same sort of concluding sentence and one assumes the phrase "best smartwatch" appears in the content ***naturally*** and ***normally***.  This type of keyword use is considered good SEO.

On the other hand, consider a page with the title:

> "Best Smartwatch from Best SmartWatch dot Com: Best Smartwatches"

and an opening sentence of:

> "Best Smartwatches are the best smartwatch that users of smartwatch
>   like best and best smartwatch can be iOS or Android or Fitbit and are
>   the best smartwatch to use for email, text message or fitness tracking
>   because they are best smartwatch"

Aside from being both a grammatical and syntactical disaster which will raise your bounce rate, the above will more than likely get you flagged as a spammer. Make sense?

Comment: and will google also see the word spam when that word is also present in domain name. And can not we do branding in page title with only one keyword from domain name at the end of page title?

Comment: Penalties last until you remove the thing that is causing the penalty. Your domain name is not considered spam, but if you have the word in the domain, in every URL, in every title, and littered throughout the content at a certain level, Google's algorithm will come to the conclusion you are spamming that word and apply a penalty. tl;dr DON'T TRY TO GAME GOOGLE. THEY ARE SMARTER THAN YOU.

Comment: I am trying to remove all the words at start and end of all things, but can't i use just a one same keyword in title's end because if i don't then the title will become one word title like `<title>Watches</title> is it good for users?

Comment: There are too many websites who do branding with domain name which contains also a keyword, can't i do that?

Comment: See my edits above. Generally speaking, I find that whenever someone has to ask "is this good for users" it generally means it isn't going to be good for users. Create your site the way you would prefer to be marketed towards. Treat your users with the same respect with which you would want to be treated.

Comment: The reason is i dont have words for each page title for 20 pages is it possible to find different words for each page title

Comment: You should if you want your pages to have maximum visibility.